# swing: Aligning JPanels in a BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing

I have a JPanel (`panel`), the layout of which is set to BoxLayout. I also have a custom class `MapRow`, which extends JPanel (and has a few components inside it in a simple FlowLayout), and I wish to add the instances of `MapRow` to `panel` in a simple, left-aligned, top-down fashion. Consider the following method:

```
public void drawMappingsPanel(JPanel panel) {
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        int s = /* aMethodCall() */;
        for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
            MapRow row = new MapRow();
            row.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
            panel.add(row);
        }
    }
```

However, when I run the code, all `MapRow` panels are centrally aligned, like below:

[image]

How can I align the `MapRow` panels to the left? The `setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT)` method doesn't seem to work...

**EDIT :** I just replaced instances of `MapRow` with dummy `JButton`s, and they got left-aligned all fine. So components such as `JButton`s can be left aligned using `setAlignmentX()`, but JPanels cannot be?

Comment: post your full code, so that someone can help you

Comment: Use a different layout manager, like [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com)

Comment: @sunil Not the full code please.... just an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: @S.L.Barth i tried to build a scenario that he tried to explain. what i got what was the panels, filled in width of the container. so i thought his problem is specific to his code. thats why i asked so :)

Comment: @sunil an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) is a sample code that reproduces the issue but where anything that is not needed to reproduce the issue has been trimmed. Read more on the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) site

Comment: What is the alignement of your FlowLayout? Is it `LEFT`? By default, FlowLayout is `CENTER`-aligned. Also, an easy trick to see what is happening is to set a border on the panels (the MapRow in your case) so that you can visualize the actual bounds of the panels.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Thank you, the alignment of FlowLayout was the problem. :-) It was using the default `CENTER`; changing it to `LEFT` did the trick. Please consider submitting your comment as the answer; I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a LEFT-alignement for you FlowLayout in MapRow. Here is a small [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org) illustrating that:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestJPanels {

    protected void initUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestJPanels.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Label-" + i);
            label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN));
            JPanel insidePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
            insidePanel.add(label);
            insidePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
            panel.add(insidePanel);
        }
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestJPanels().initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```